# Ways to use SFTP from Classic ASP Script

Tags: asp-classic, sftp

What options are there to transfer files securely SFTP / SSH or any other sercure way 
using only pure Classic ASP script where no komponents or Server.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
is allowed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP, need to use SFTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805/asp-need-to-use-sftp)

Answer (score 0):

I'd cheat and upload a .net script that can do the work for you using something like SharpZipLib (http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

Most servers have at least .net 1.1 installed (more probably .net 2) and this should be able to do what you want, no DLL's need registering and you can run .net along side asp no problems are all.

Comment: did you mean Tamir Gal's SharpSSH for .NET ?

Comment: Ooops yes, sorry. I've been working with sharpziplib too of late. Thanks for the correction!